# I'm trying to use Shippo to get a USPS shipping label to send within the US, but can't seem to get any rates to appear

Tags: shippo

This is my request:

Address from:

```
Array(
[name] => Mr.John
[street1] => 1234 Market Street
[city] => San Francisco
[zip] => 95432
[state] => CA
[phone] => +1 415 123 1234
[email] => mrjohn+test@gmail.com
[country] => US
[object_purpose] => QUOTE
[company] => Shippo
```

)

Address to :

```
Array(
[name] => Ms. Jane
[street1] => 1234 Mission Street
[city] => San Francisco
[zip] => 91234
[state] => CA
[phone] => +1 415 234 2345
[email] => msjane+test@gmail.com
[country] => US
[object_purpose] => QUOTE
[street2] =>
[company] =>
```

)

Custom Item :

```
Shippo_Object Object(
[_apiKey:protected] => xxxx
[_values:protected] => Array (
    [object_created] => [date]
    [object_updated] => [date]
    [object_id] => xxxxx
    [object_owner] => sender+test@gmail.com
    [object_state] => VALID
    [description] => IPhone 6
    [quantity] => 1
    [net_weight] => 3
    [mass_unit] => lb
    [value_amount] => 450
    [value_currency] => USD
    [origin_country] => US
    [tariff_number] =>
    [metadata] => Order ID #123123
)
[_unsavedValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object (
    [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array (
    )
)
[_transientValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object (
    [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array (
        )
)
[_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array (
)
```

)

Custom Shipping :

```
   Shippo_Object Object( 
[_apiKey:protected] => xxxx
[_values:protected] => Array ( 
    [object_created] => [date]
    [object_updated] => [date]
    [object_id] => xxxxx
    [object_owner] => sender+test@gmail.com
    [object_state] => VALID 
    [certify_signer] => Mr. John
    [certify] => 1 [items] => Array ( 
        [0] => xxxx 
        ) 
    [non_delivery_option] => ABANDON 
    [contents_type] => MERCHANDISE 
    [contents_explanation] => IPhone 6 
    [exporter_reference] => 
    [importer_reference] => 
    [invoice] => #123123 
    [commercial_invoice] => 
    [license] => 
    [certificate] => 
    [notes] => 
    [eel_pfc] =>  
    [aes_itn] => 
    [disclaimer] => 
    [incoterm] => 
    [metadata] => Order ID #123123 
) 
[_unsavedValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object ( 
    [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array ( 
    ) 
) 
[_transientValues:protected] => Shippo_Util_Set Object ( 
    [_elts:Shippo_Util_Set:private] => Array ( 
    ) 
) 
[_retrieveOptions:protected] => Array ( 
    )
)
```

Am I miss something? I have address_to, address_from, custom item, and custom shipping all filled out.

Comment: Also, it's it just 'weight' and not 'net_weight' in requests?

Answer (score 4):

I’m from the Shippo team here!

Everything in your call seems good. Please double check that you have your USPS account activated - you can edit it via the [Carrier Accounts Endpoint](https://goshippo.com/shipping-api/carrier-accounts) or on the [Carriers Page](https://goshippo.com/user/carriers) directly.

Since the shipment is domestic, you won’t need to add the “customs item”, nor “customs shipping” information. You should only provide this information when creating an international shipment.

Remove +1 from each phone number, that’s not needed and may cause problems.

Hope that’s helpful.